# SCHEME - Count number of procedures that are not primitive

Tags: list, scheme, procedure, primitive

I have to make a function where I have to count the number of procedures that are not primitive inside a list. 
Here are some examples:

```
(nprocs '(+ (cuadrado 1) (* 2 (inc1 3))))                     => 0
(nprocs (+ (cuadrado 1) (* 2 (inc1 3))))                      => ERROR
(nprocs (list + (list cuadrado 1) (list * 2 (list inc1 3))))  => 2
```

I tried this:

```
(define (cuadrado x) (* x x))
(define inc1 (lambda (x) (+ x 1)))

(define nprocs
  (lambda (fun)
    (if (list? fun)
        (if(procedure? (car fun))
           (+ 1 (nprocs (cdr fun)))
           (nprocs (cdr fun)))
        0)
   )
)
```

This code isn't working, hope someone can help.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The first is a quoted list so `+` and `*` are symbols and not procedures. The second one you try to evaluate the expression and let the result be passed to `nprocs` while the last example uses `list` so that `+` and other symbols may be evaluated to procedures. Only the last is correct. Alternatively you can use `\`(,+ (,curado 1) (,* 2 (,inc1 3)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A list is composed of cons cells and atoms. Here's the canonical way of processing a list, counting non-primitive procedures on your way:

```
(define (nprocs sxp)
  (cond
    ; cons cell -> process car and cdr
    ((pair? sxp) (+ (nprocs (car sxp)) (nprocs (cdr sxp))))
    ; atom -> is it a procedure that is not a primitive?
    ((and (procedure? sxp) (not (primitive? sxp))) 1)
    ; atom, not or procedure or a primitive
    (else 0)))
```

Testing:

```
> (nprocs '(+ (cuadrado 1) (* 2 (inc1 3)))) 
0
> (nprocs (list + (list cuadrado 1) (list * 2 (list inc1 3))))
2
```

Answer (score 1):

The `nprocs` procedure must traverse a list of lists, testing whether each atom is a procedure that is *not* primitive, and adding the results of all sublists. This is simpler if we use a `cond` for the conditions, and use the standard template for traversing a list of lists:

```
(define (nprocs fun)
  (cond ((null? fun) 0)
        ((not (pair? fun))
         (if (and (procedure? fun) (not (primitive? fun))) 1 0))
        (else (+ (nprocs (car fun))
                 (nprocs (cdr fun))))))
```

It works as long as we pass actual procedures in the list (not just symbols):

```
(nprocs (list + (list cuadrado 1) (list * 2 (list inc1 3))))
=> 2
```

If the same non-primitive procedure appears more then once, it'll be counted several times. If that's a problem, it'll be easier to remove the duplicates if we use a more idiomatic solution leveraging built-in higher-order procedures. For example, in Racket:

```
(define (nprocs fun)
  (count (lambda (e) (and (procedure? e) (not (primitive? e))))
         (remove-duplicates (flatten fun))))
```